# Clementine/Gnome multimedia keys don't stick

Tags: gnome, keyboard, multimedia, clementine

My keyboard has the multimedia keys on the function keys, with <kbd>Fn + F6</kbd> to play/pause etc. The problem is these don't work in my music player (Clementine) after rebooting. If I go into the *Preferences -> Global Shortcuts*, and ***check and uncheck*** that box for "Use Gnome's shortcut keys", then they work again. Meaning, at boot it is unchecked, and they don't work, but if I toggle the checkbox on and off then they magically work again.

So what does that checkbox actually do?  Is there some way I can automate whatever it does in a script at boot time, so that my multimedia keys will always work without the stuffing around?

My keyboard is a Logitech MK250.  I'm on 11.10, with gnome-shell.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused this issue, but it has vanished after upgrading to 12.04.